# Why does the scrollbar disappear?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My scrollbar disappears in Chrome after applying any CSS to it.

I'm also using React for this project if this something what has to do with my issue.

My CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't disappear it just overrides other styles which you have to add manually.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000;
}

body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```